# Postgres: detect current transaction level

Tags: postgresql

What's PostgreSQL's equivalent of [`select @@trancount`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187967.aspx)?

Comment: `select 1` would be the equivalent

Comment: :-D   hha ha ha !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgresql uses savepoints. There are not nested transactions.

And you can name them.

I suggest you to start here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-savepoint.html

Comment: The same goes: is there any SQL code to detect if any savepoints have been set on the current connection/session

Comment: Since I'm checking for stray transactions and if you can't nest transactions, I guess I could check wether `rollback` throws the appropriate error, if not a transaction was active!

Comment: @StijnSanders, it seems to be not possible to detect: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75474/in-postgres-how-to-get-a-list-of-current-defined-savepoint

Comment: Also, because postgresql, and Oracle, have not nested transaction, translating such code from sql server needs an intense rewrite.

Comment: Thanks, I've accepted your answer. Also: I found out a _loose_ `rollback` throws a warning, not an error, so you need to use libpq's `PQsetNoticeProcessor` to catch it.

Comment: Savepoints are not really the same. A `commit` or `rollback` affects the whole transaction regardless of the number of savepoints - unlike SQL Server where you might need multiple commits to "really" commit a transaction.